# Adding new variables makes regression coefficients individually insignificant

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, multicollinearity

I have a multiple regression where all my coefficients are significant. When I add new variables my initial variables become insignificant. Furthermore, my new variables (that in a simple regression are significant) turn out to be also insignificant.

My questions are:

1. What are the possible reasons for this change of significance?
2. What are the methods and possible solutions to solve this issue?

Comment: almost certainly the additional predictors are strongly related to some linear combination of your original predictors. This issue is discussed in many answers on site (try a search on *multicollinear* or *multicollinearity* for example)

Comment: If it is about p=0.04 becoming 0.06, then the solution is to not attach too much importance to that. 0.04 does not prove a variable is important and 0.06 does not make it unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

As @Glen_b already said it is certainly that the variables are strongly related, so you have multicollinearity. You can make a correlation matrix for the variables, to check if the variables are indeed strongly related. Based on the correlation values, you could add interaction-terms to your model between variables that are highly correlated, as these might be significant.